# Issue with AVPlayer in Swift application

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I get a mp4 video with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput class and save it under the Documents folder of the application, but when I try to play the video with a AVPlayer class, I see nothing in the custom UIView. Below the code:

```
player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

I tried to save the video in Camera Roll and I can see the video under the gallery correctly.

EDIT:

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path.absoluteString)
if let pathComponent = url.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4") {
  let filePath = pathComponent.path
  let fileManager = FileManager.default
  if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
     print("FILE AVAILABLE")
  } else {
     print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
  }
} else {
  print("FILE PATH NOT AVAILABLE")
}
```

I tried the code above and the output is "FILE AVAILABLE". The file is stored under this path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/27BDD2E1-815B-422B-96A9-E166BE154950/Documents/video.mp4

Some can help me to find a solution about this problem?

Comment: How do you construct the `URL` you pass to `AVPlayer`?

Comment: I get the 'URL' from 'AVCaptureMovieFileOutput' object.

Comment: I've faced that problem and a hacky solution was to add `"file://"` (if it doesn't have it) to the beginning of an url (something like `let url = URL(string: "file://\(pathComponent.path)")`). Don't know what a "proper" way to resolve it, but it worked for me

Comment: @LëshaTurkowski I tried both modes but the result is the same: black view (seated as background color).

Answer (score 1):

Try using Apple's own example - use following `PlayerView` class:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    // Override UIView property
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Then set it for the `videoView` property:

```
let videoView = PlayerView()
```

And then use it:

```
videoView.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
videoView.player?.play()
```

Comment: @LuigiMargheritti well, it works for everyone else - that must mean that the problem is in the way you create the URL - update the question with code related to that

Comment: I added the code where I check the availability of the file. I tried to download the MP4 file and added it as resource of the project. It doesn't start.